# Failed to install bootloader /dev/mapper no /dev/sda

Tags: grub2, partitioning, bootloader, boot-repair

Ubuntu was running no problems on this laptop before I attempted a reinstall. I simply want a standard default install, no dual-boot.

During installation bootloader failed to install. I continued without a bootloader hoping to install grub from the live cd afterwards (i hoped boot-repair would work). I am confused by the /dev/mapper I keep being greeted with. For example `sudo fdisk -l` returns

```
 ~ $ sudo fdisk -l
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: invalid flag 0x91e6 of partition table 5 will be corrected by w(rite)

Disk /dev/sda: 64.0 GB, 64023257088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7783 cylinders, total 125045424 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00028cbd

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *         512      500223      249856   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          500734   250081791   124790529    5  Extended
/dev/sda5   ?  1454279609  3201150582   873435487   b7  BSDI fs

Disk /dev/sdb: 64.0 GB, 64023257088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7783 cylinders, total 125045424 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0: 128.0 GB, 128041877504 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250081792 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00028cbd

                              Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p1   *         512      500223      249856   83  Linux
/dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p2          500734   250081791   124790529    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p5          500736   250081791   124790528   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p1: 255 MB, 255852544 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31 cylinders, total 499712 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
fdisk: unable to read /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Boot-repair returns the following boot-repair report http://paste2.org/cN9Zs1ad

Here is a [link to a screenshot of my gparted](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghpyi95of76768y/2014-12-30%2012.23.33.jpg?dl=0).

Thank you for any help. I have spent several days to try to resolve this now!

Comment: I am using live USB, if I boot without it I just get a blank black screen flashing cursor.

Comment: Are you trying to install cinnamon?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for any help :-). (And previously i was running 14.04)

Comment: I would recommend booting from a live cd and removing all partitions, effectively wiping your entire hard drive. Then try the Installation again. Remember that ppa's for Ubuntu do not necessarily work with Mint. I don't know if boot-repair is supported on Mint.

Comment: Thank you. Could you direct me to some instructions on how to do this. I know how yo bring up the partitions in gparted. I also know if i boot the live usb (no cd on vaio z) i can choose the install option with a manual install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a clean install, I would recommend booting from a live cd and removing all partitions, effectively wiping your entire hard drive. Then try the Installation again.

Remember that ppa's for Ubuntu do not necessarily work with Mint. I don't know if boot-repair is supported on Mint.

## How to delete partitions using gparted

1. Start gparted from a live cd ("try ubuntu" mode)
2. Select the correct device (physical hard drive) in the right upper corner

[image]

3. Click(top menu) on Device > Create Partition Table
4. Select MSDos or GPT and click apply (you might get a warning about not being able to inform the kernel)

[image]

5. **Reboot** and start the installer.

Comment: I plan to follow this advice--yes i just want a fresh install. I am not sure how i can wipe partitions before reinstalling. Do you mean by choosing the manual partition install option when i boot from live USB?

Comment: I will add instructions please be patient :)

Comment: Do these instructions help you?

Comment: Thank you. I would add that in the upper right corner where you have /dev/sda I have /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0 (119.25 GiB) then there is /dev/sda (59.63 GiB) then /dev/sdb (59.63 GiB) then /dev/sdc (1.87 GiB) which I understand is my live USB. The first one isw... is the only one with partitions on it. This is what has been confusing me as all advice I find refers to /dev/sda. So should I create partition table on the first one 119.25GiB.

Comment: What I understand from your comment is that you have two physical drives (/dev/sdb and /dev/sdc) that are acting like they are one (/dev/mapper/isw_...). Maybe as a raid?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by two physical drives. In the top right hand corner (as you screenshot) I have the four drives listed in my last comment. I just want to clarify that when I follow your instructions the correct device to choose is the /dev/mapper/isw... one

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: When choosing the sda, sdb or sdc ones the partition column just says unallocated. Whereas the /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0 has two partitions on it /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p1 and /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p2 the p1 is ext2 and unders flags says boot. I will add a screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19847/discussion-between-sav-econ-and-galgalesh).

Answer (score 0):

[galgalesh's](https://askubuntu.com/a/566984/252173) instructions worked for me. A couple of points to add. In gparted I selected each of the drives /dev/mapper /dev/sda and /dev/sdb (not sdc as this is the live usb I believe) and then did step 3 create partition table. Once I had done this i tried to reinstall but it failed. However I rebooted and tried the reinstall and it worked OK. I was presented with a different screen on the reinstall after I chose the erase everything option I was asked whether i wanted to install on sda or sdb i didnt get this screen in the past. I chose sda and it went through the install process.